# Getting sampling rate down on Arduino through serial transmission

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, adc

I'm using an Arduino to read analog values from microphones to triangulate the location of bullets. The triangulation actually happens in Python, where it parses the string into arrays and then processes it, and I have that function working. For my function to triangulate with enough accuracy, however, I would need to significantly lower the time between the analog sampling of the pins. Ideally, I'd like a sample every microsecond for 4 pins, although I do have some wiggle room. I'm using an Arduino Uno. Here's the code I have so far.

```cpp
/*
This code reads in values on analog pins A0-A3 and sends the values
over serial. The outputs can be checked using the serial monitor.

created 03/22/18
*/
const int sensor1Pin = 0;
const int sensor2Pin = 1;
const int sensor3Pin = 2;
const int sensor4Pin = 3;
float sensorVal[] = {0,0,0,0};

unsigned long time;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(2000000);                 //setup serial connection
}

void loop()
{
  time = micros();
  sensorVal[0] = analogRead(sensor1Pin);
  sensorVal[1] = analogRead(sensor2Pin);
  sensorVal[2] = analogRead(sensor3Pin);
  sensorVal[3] = analogRead(sensor4Pin);

  Serial.print(sensorVal[0]);     //read xpin and send value over serial
  Serial.print("\t");                         //send a "tab" over serial
  Serial.print(sensorVal[1]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(sensorVal[2]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(sensorVal[3]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println();                           //ends the line of serial communication

  delayMicroseconds(1);
}
```

I added the timer so I could get an idea of how long I have between each sample. With the timer, I'm getting between 1000-2000 μs between the samples. I recognize that my sampling rate will go down with the timer removed, but I was curious if there's anything I can do to significantly reduce the time between the samples.

Comment: [`analogRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/) takes 100 microseconds. And why are you reading again from the analog pins with previous analog value as a pin number?

Comment: Is there another way to read from the analog pins that would be faster than analog read?

Comment: The reading twice was a mistake. I removed it. Thank you.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/51429

Comment: Does that mean in order to read all 4 pins, it will take 400 microseconds?

Comment: There is a single ADC and the pins are multiplexed. You can't read multiple pins simultaneously.